# Prevent request mapping from being registered in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my application, I have an abstract controller that handles common CRUD behavior already and can be instantiated for certain entities.

```java
@RestController
public abstract class DefaultRestController<T, U extends Model> {

  @GetMapping
  @NotNull
  public Page<U> findAll(@NotNull final Pageable pageable) {
    return service.getAll(pageable);
  }

  // more CRUD methods here
}
```

Now, when I override this controller, I might want to keep most of the methods, but customize some, while still keeping the request mapping. For instance, say I want a `UserController` that extends the above abstract class and I still want a `GET /` mapping, however, the method signature shall change. For instance, I want this instead:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends DefaultRestController<UserDTO, User> {

  @GetMapping
  public Page<User> findAllFiltered(@NotNull final Pageable pageable, Specification spec) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is invalid, because now I have two handlers for the same mapping (`GET /`). What I'd like to do now is override the `findAll()` method and annotate it with a custom annotation like `@IgnoreRequestMapping` to disable it.

I first tried the approach described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/17787#issuecomment-453427452). However, that would only work if I want to disable the mapping altogether, not "override" it.

In addition I tried creating a custom version of the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping` and overriding `registerHandlerMethod(Object handler, Method method, RequestMappingInfo mapping)` in a way that the actual `registerHandlerMethod()` is only called when no `@IgnoreRequestMapping` is present on the `method`, but that didn't work either.

I'm not very familiar with the internals of Spring. Could someone please help me achieve the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you only want to extend parts of your parent class - Java does not allow that. You could override the original method and use a different path for it, but you have to implement it.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController extends DefaultRestController<UserDTO, User> {

  @GetMapping("/unfiltered")
  @NotNull
  public Page<U> findAll(@NotNull final Pageable pageable) {
    throw new RuntimeException("not implemented");
  }

  @GetMapping
  public Page<User> findAllFiltered(@NotNull final Pageable pageable, Specification spec) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Of course this is a bit hacky (because there is no such thing like `@NoMapping`, so you should just use a different path for your filtered method - or don't extend your `DefaultRestController`.

Comment: Thanks, that's also what I thought, but as you said, the approach to give the mapping some "random" name is hacky, especially as it would still be listed in Swagger docs, etc. Isn't there some way to create such an annotation?

Comment: I don't think so. You can at least hide a method from Swagger with `@ApiIgnore`.
But of course, the best way would be an implementation for both of these methods.